dbghelp.dll: Cannot open: File exists When building QGIS in Windows
I'm trying to build the QGIS source in Windows (11) and i am following the instructions from here:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL.md#4-building-on-windows
I tried to follow all steps in section "4. Building on Windows"
went through the steps one by one but when I ran
bootstrap.cmd qgis-dev

I get this error
+ tar -C '/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Debuggers/x64' -xjvf /tmp/qgis.tar.bz2 --xform 's,.*/,,' apps/qgis-ltr/dbghelp.dll apps/qgis-ltr/symsrv.dll
+ /bin/tar -C '/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Debuggers/x64' -xjvf /tmp/qgis.tar.bz2 --xform 's,.*/,,' apps/qgis-ltr/dbghelp.dll apps/qgis-ltr/symsrv.dll
apps/qgis-ltr/dbghelp.dll
/bin/tar: dbghelp.dll: Cannot open: File exists
apps/qgis-ltr/symsrv.dll
/bin/tar: symsrv.dll: Cannot open: File exists
/bin/tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
2024-11-14 12:51:53: ERROR: error 2 on line 390
++ local i=1
++ caller 1
+ faillog
+ log 'FAILED: 2'
++ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
+ echo '2024-11-14 12:51:53: FAILED: 2'
2024-11-14 12:51:53: FAILED: 2
+ '[' -f /cygdrive/d/QGIS/OSGeo4W/osgeo4w-build/scripts/fail ']'
+ finishlog
+ '[' -f /cygdrive/d/QGIS/OSGeo4W/osgeo4w-build/scripts/finish ']'
+ log END
++ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
+ echo '2024-11-14 12:51:53: END'
2024-11-14 12:51:53: END
+ return 1
++ errlog 1 1
++ log 'ERROR: error 1 on line 1'
+++ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
++ echo '2024-11-14 12:51:53: ERROR: error 1 on line 1'
2024-11-14 12:51:53: ERROR: error 1 on line 1
++ set -x
++ local i=1
++ caller 1
Thu Nov 14 12:51:53 MPST 2024: qgis-dev FAILED WITH 1

I'm not sure What I did wrong since I just went through all the steps.
Anyone have any idea?
